# Git pull “permission denied” when using shell_exec in PHP

Tags: php, git

I'm trying to make a hook on bitbucket, that executes a php file, and this file executes the pull command:

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git pull');
```

The pull command works fine on the SSH console, but the PHP returns the error:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

The command ***--version*** shows the path to git is right, ***whoiami*** returns the same user on both, so I don't know if it is a permission issue.

What can be going wrong?

**Edit:** An additional issue: the alias I added for **git** don't work on PHP, only the full path as above. Via terminal it works just fine. Maybe it's the same reason why the key don't work in php.

**Edit 2:** `$PATH` is different on both.

Comment: Sounds like your SSH key was not added to that git repository (a permission issue).

Comment: how are you calling this shell_exec()-containing script? via webrowser/http? Shouldn't it return the webserver's UID in that case, not the "same user" you got?

Comment: The public key is on the repository. I can pull from the server, the issue is only when running the command from a php file. And yes, i'm running the php file via http, and the whoami returns the same user name. Is it possible to have both user with same namebut different privileges?

Answer (score 2):

When you run this command within a PHP script you are not running the command as yourself:

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git pull');
```

The reason it works from the terminal console is you run the command as yourself from the console. But on a  web server, you are not the user running the command. Remember: When you run PHP on a web server, it is a an Apache module. Meaning the web server user—which could be `www-data`, `root` or even `apache` on some systems—is running the PHP script which then runs the `shell_exec` command.

So it would never work as you have it setup. Perhaps you can kludge something together that would allow a key-pair to be used by the web server for these purposes, but that seems like a security risk waiting to happen.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a complete noob on this. I understand that the users may be different, but when I run **shell_exec('whoami')**, it says the user is the same as when I run from termianl. And when I list the running users, it lists only this user and says that it is running apache. That's confusing. As I said above, **$PATH** is different on both, could it mean something?